# Create custom page using wordpress plgin

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am beginner in wordpress so my question might be foolish but I searched various way but could not find the solution so that writing here.

I want to create a wordpress plugin that can create a custom user registration page in word press.

First I created page template and placed in theme directory, Then I created page and selected template from attribute and page created. No problem upto this.

Now  want to create same thing in others wordpress by plugins.

So I added below code in plugin

> ```
>     $_p = array();
>     $_p['post_title'] = $the_page_title;
>     $_p['post_content'] = "This text may be overridden by the plugin. You shouldn't edit it.";
>     $_p['post_status'] = 'publish';
>     $_p['post_type'] = 'page';
>     $_p['comment_status'] = 'closed';
>     $_p['ping_status'] = 'closed';
>     $_p['post_category'] = array(1); // the default 'Uncatrgorised'
>
>     // Insert the post into the database
>     $the_page_id = wp_insert_post( $_p );
>
>     if ( !$the_page_id ) {
>       wp_die( 'Error creating template page' );       
>     } else {
>       update_post_meta( $the_page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page-userregistration.php' ); 
>     }
> ```

Its working fine if template file is copied in theme directory but not without it.

I tried several solutions to use template from plugin directory like

> add_filter('single_template','add_user_registration_page')

But its not working.

Any help or code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this example plugin which shows how to ship page templates with plugin https://github.com/tommcfarlin/page-template-example/

Comment: Thank you sir... It helped me. The way I am doing for creating custom page, is it correct ?